# How to set command arguments to launch with in Visual Studio's profiler for C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, profiling, profiler

Just like there is the "Command Arguments" option for Debug launch in project properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After slightly more than two months, I myself finally found it. Posting this answer for anyone else that might wonder.

Right-click on the target binary executable and click **Properties** (Visual Studio 2012+).

There you'll find it all.

Comment: Where do you click on the executable?